# Using BASS_StreamCreateFile in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, bass

`BASS_StreamCreateFile(path,offset,length,BassFlags)` always returns '`0`'. I am not understanding how to use this function. Need help on the usage of BassFlags.

PS : Using this with the help of WPF Sound Visualization Library.

Comment: btw. can you post the code where you create the stream?

Answer (score 0):

Since `0` only informs you that there's an error, you should check what kind of error it is:

```
int BASS_ErrorGetCode();
```

This gives you the errorcode for the **recent** error.

Here's the list of possible error codes (= return values):

```
BASS_ERROR_INIT // BASS_Init has not been successfully called.
BASS_ERROR_NOTAVAIL // Only decoding channels (BASS_STREAM_DECODE) are allowed when using the "no sound" device. The BASS_STREAM_AUTOFREE // flag is also unavailable to decoding channels.
BASS_ERROR_ILLPARAM // The length must be specified when streaming from memory.
BASS_ERROR_FILEOPEN // The file could not be opened.
BASS_ERROR_FILEFORM // The file's format is not recognised/supported.
BASS_ERROR_CODEC    // The file uses a codec that is not available/supported. This can apply to WAV and AIFF files, and also MP3 files when using the "MP3-free" BASS version.
BASS_ERROR_FORMAT   // The sample format is not supported by the device/drivers. If the stream is more than stereo or the BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT flag is used, it could be that they are not supported.
BASS_ERROR_SPEAKER  // The specified SPEAKER flags are invalid. The device/drivers do not support them, they are attempting to assign a stereo stream to a mono speaker or 3D functionality is enabled.
BASS_ERROR_MEM  // There is insufficient memory.
BASS_ERROR_NO3D // Could not initialize 3D support.
BASS_ERROR_UNKNOWN  // Some other mystery problem!
```

*(from `bass.h`)*

Also make shure you have **initialised** BASS properly - `BASS_Init()` must get called *before* you create a stream:

```
BOOL BASS_Init(
    int device, // The device to use... -1 = default device, 0 = no sound, 1 = first real output device
    DWORD freq, // Output sample rate
    DWORD flags, // A combination of flags
    HWND win, // The application's main window... 0 = the current foreground window (use this for console applications)
    GUID *clsid // Class identifier of the object to create, that will be used to initialize DirectSound... NULL = use default
);
```

**Example:**

```
int device = -1; // Default device
int freq = 44100; // Sample rate

BASS_Init(device, freq, 0, 0, NULL); // Init BASS
```

Comment: Bass is initialised properly. I just want to know how the BASS_StreamCreateFile() works. I have a working code in C# but the VB code doesn't work. The functions returns 0 always.

Comment: Thats why you should check the *real* error code. `0` tells you only that there's an error. Can you post the your code where you call `BASS_StreamCreateFile()`?